# Некорректно считываются русские символы из текстового файла на python. Как исправить?

Tags: python

```
filer = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
task = filer.read()
print(task)
```

Пример

В `dictionary.txt`

```
Привет мир
```

Вывод:

```
РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РјРёСЂ
```

Comment: Укажите кодировку: `filer = open('dictionary.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score -3):

Скорее всего проблема в кодировке файла, в начале файла можно добавить

`#!/usr/bin/env python3
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Если вы конечно используете линукс. Если винду, можете попробовать без первой строки. Если все это не помогает, запустите скрипт из cmd/терминала. В если ничего не помогает, напишите, какую ide вы используете. У меня была похожая проблема на vs code, после перехода на atom все заработало. Можете попробовать.

Comment: Эти строки никак не влияют на то как читается текст из файла

Comment: это специальные комментарии, которые указывают как декодировать файл. Тут вы можете почитать об этом подробнее https://habr.com/ru/post/135913/

Comment: Я в курсе что это за комментарии. Второй комментарий указывает кодировку текущего модуля, но если бы была проблема в кодировке модуля, была бы синтаксическая ошибка. И на Python3 если модуль в utf-8, явное указание кодировки модуля не нужны на любой системе. Проблема не в кодировке модуля, а в том что при чтении из файла файл прочитался в кодировке cp1251, а нужно в utf-8.